# Circling and selecting a text

Tags: android, geometry

I am developing an app in and i have a html page on the webView in android. that html page would have lots of lines of text, no images. when i circle a particular part of  that text, the text within that circle should be highlighted and i need to find the co-ordinates of the circle. how do i do that in android. pls help me out.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a pretty complex task...

I haven't done this myself but from the looks of the API you will probably want to use a [GestureOverlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html) on top of the WebView. This will allow you to recognize gestures and get their coordinates. However recognizing just a circle or oval and not something else like a square or a squiggly line may require some more advanced mathematics. In the end I don't believe it is possible to select non-contiguous pieces of text so if your circle overlaps multiple lines of text but isn't the width of the entire screen I don't know what you would want to select.

One thing you could do is simulate a highlight by obtaining and sending a generated [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28long,%20long,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int%29) to the WebView's [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method that starts at the top left of the circle gesture and ends and the bottom right. That would likely result in a highlight, but it may not be exactly what the user expects, especially if they did something weird like draw a really tall thin oval.

Comment: actually what i want to do is that, when i circle a part of text(it can spreading over multiple lines but not cover the entire width of the screen) that text should be highlighted and i need to associate a comment with that highlighted text using a database..

Comment: but thanks for those suggestions satur9nine .. i would try that out and keep u posted about the results..